# Sublime Text: Add "Permute Lines -> Shuffle" shortcut key

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

I wondered if anyone could help me out.

In sublime text, when I want to shuffle some lines (for example if I had a list of colour names and wanted them in random order). I've been using Ctrl+Shift+P, and then writing shuffle to get the "Permute lines: Shuffle" command. This is fairly quick but I'd love to have a shortcut for it as I use it very often. I know there's a file I can change but I don't know how to write the command.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Items that appear in the command palette are stored in `sublime-commands` files. If you use the `View Package File` command from the command palette and enter `sublime-commands` as the filter text, the list of all files in all packages that add commands to the command palette will be displayed.

The first part of the filename shows you what package is contributing the command, and commands that are part of core Sublime are in the `Default/` package, so choosing the file `Default/Default.sublime-commands` will show you the commands Sublime ships with (note that some packages include a file named `Default.sublime-commands`, so make sure you're picking the `Default/` version).

If you look in that file and search for the command that you see in the command palette, you'll find this (reformatted here to not be all one line):

```
{ 
    "caption": "Permute Lines: Shuffle", 
    "command": "permute_lines", 
    "args": {"operation": "shuffle"} 
},
```

This shows you the `command` and `args` you need to apply in a key binding.

For commands that also appear in the menu (or are bound to other keys and you want to remap them) you can also open the Sublime console with `View > Show Console` in the menu and enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`. Now when you choose a menu item or press a key, the command that is being executed will be logged for you. The logging remains in effect until you enter `sublime.log_commands(False)` in the console or restart Sublime.

In this case doing that and then choosing `Edit > Permute Lines > Shuffle` will log this in the console:

```
command: permute_lines {"operation": "shuffle"}
```

This shows the same command and arguments that are required (if any).